# Using discriminator together with allOf

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I'm trying document an api endpoint using [swagger-php v2.0](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) but the swagger documentation is not correctly generated.

My usecase is that I need to accept 2 different payloads from the same endpoint and the some keys can only be present in the given context.

As for the official documentation it can be achieved using `discriminator` along with `allOf` and [this is the example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#models-with-polymorphism-support) given in OpenAPI (Swagger) Specification.

For clarity I'll post a shrunken down version here

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "FooBar": {
        "type": "object",
        "discriminator": "type",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
            "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {
            "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "name",
            "type"
        ]
        },
        "foo": {
        "allOf": [
            {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/FooBar"
            },
            {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "unique_to_foo_field": {
                "type": "string",
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "unique_to_foo_field"
            ]
            }
        ]
        },
        "bar": {
        "allOf": [
            {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/FooBar"
            },
            {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "unique_to_bar_field": {
                "type": "string",
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "unique_to_bar_field"
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to convert this for swagger-php and the one I came up with is as follows, but seems it's not correct. I seek advice to correct it, thanks.

```
/**
* @SWG\Definition(
*      definition="model:FooBar",
*      type="object",
*      discriminator="type",
*      required={"type", "name"},
*      @SWG\Property(property="type", type="string"),
*      @SWG\Property(property="name", type="string"),
* )
*
* @SWG\Definition(
*      definition="model:foo",
*      allOf={
*          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/model:FooBar"),
*          @SWG\Schema(
*              required={"unique_to_foo_field"},
*              type="object",
*              @SWG\Property(property="unique_to_foo_field", type="integer")
*          )
*      }
* )
*
* @SWG\Definition(
*      definition="model:bar",
*      allOf={
*          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/model:FooBar"),
*          @SWG\Schema(
*              required={"unique_to_bar_field"},
*              type="object",
*              @SWG\Property(property="unique_to_foo_field", type="integer")
*          )
*      }
* )
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to come up with an answer with a help of a friend.

And for the benefit of others who might stumble upon the same issue, I'm posting my own answer for this.

```
/**
* @SWG\Post(
*   @SWG\Parameter(
*       name="Create a foo",
*       in="body",
*       @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/foo")
*   ),
*   @SWG\Parameter(
*       name="create a bar",
*       in="body",
*       @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/bar")
*   )
* )
*
* @SWG\Definition(
*      definition="FooBar",
*      discriminator="type",
*      required={"type", "name"},
*      @SWG\Property(property="type", type="string", enum={"foofoo","barbar"}),
*      @SWG\Property(property="name", type="string"),
* )
*
* @SWG\Definition(
*      definition="foo",
*      allOf={
*          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/FooBar"),
*          @SWG\Schema(
*              required={"unique_to_foo_field"},
*              type="object",
*              @SWG\Property(property="unique_to_foo_field", type="integer"),
*              @SWG\Property(property="type", type="string", default="foofoo"),
*          )
*      }
* )
*
* @SWG\Definition(
*      definition="bar",
*      allOf={
*          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/FooBar"),
*          @SWG\Schema(
*              required={"unique_to_bar_field"},
*              type="object",
*              @SWG\Property(property="unique_to_foo_field", type="integer"),
*              @SWG\Property(property="type", type="string", default="barbar"),
*          )
*      }
* )
*/
```